# SunCertPathBuilderException in Spring Tool Suite 4 when starting a project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, certificate

Anyone know how I could pass the proxy if this is the real problem in order to be able to start a new pring starter project. To clarify you have down here the error and what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally this was the solution:

1. Go to the Spring [page](https://spring.io) and download the certificate from padlock in the left of the URL.
2. Include it in the keystore of the java version used to initialize the Spring tool suite `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin>"keytool -import -alias springiocertificate -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\springiocertificate.cer`